# Formal groups: why the axiom $F(X,Y) \equiv X+Y \pmod {\langle X,Y\rangle^2}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Whenever reading about formal groups, this axiom has always appeared to me as a bit artificial, at least compared to the other axioms.

To explain what I mean, suppose that $R$ is a ring, and that we are given a one-parameter (formal) group scheme structure on $R[[X]]$, the ring of formal power series in $X$. If we put $G = \text{Spf }(R[[X]])$, the multiplication $G\times G\to G$ corresponds to a continuous map of topological $R$-algebras (the comultiplication):

$$R[[T]] \to R[[X]] \widehat{\otimes} R[[Y]] = R[[X,Y]].$$

The image of $T$ in $R[[X,Y]]$ is a formal power series $F(X,Y) \in R[[X,Y]],$ and the axioms for a group scheme translate into the usual formal group axioms for $F$, that is, *except the axiom $F(X,Y) \equiv X + Y  \pmod {\langle X,Y\rangle^2}$*. So, what is the reason for throwing it in? Is it just because the formal groups which appear "in nature" satisfy it?

Comment: Since $F(X.0)=X$ and $F(0,Y)=Y$ (if we suppose $0$ is the group unit) then $F(X,Y)=X+Y+\dots$ seems necessary - i.e. mark me confused as well :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that condition is used to ensure that $T\mapsto F(X,Y)$ actually gives a homomorphism, i.e., that you can substitute $F(X,Y)$ in for $T$ for a series $G(T)\in R[[T]]$. So it is implicit in the definition of group object structure on $\mathrm{Spf}(R[[T]])$. In the definition of a formal group law just in terms of power series, this is included explicitly since there isn't explicit mention being made of a map $R[[T]]\rightarrow R[[X]]\hat{\otimes}_RR[[Y]]$.

Comment: Hi @KeenanKidwell, thanks for your comment! In order to be able to substitute $F$ for $T$, isn't all that is required that $F \in \langle X,Y \rangle$? Maybe I'm not understanding...

Comment: Dear @Marie, You're right, it must be more than that. I think that if you assume that the identity section is $T\mapsto 0$, you can do a computation in $G(G\times G)$ to show that the congruence condition must hold. I haven't worked this out completely though, so your mileage may vary :)